# Normalize multiple Tradingview 0cross indicators to keep within the same range and still cross 0 when they should?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm combining three 0cross indicators in Tradingview however they scale differently so to solve the problem I applied the Normalize function after some research. I then noticed that though the scaling was now within the range, they no longer crossed the 0 line when they should compared to the none scaled version.  Is there any way to normalize and have multiple plotted lines still be consistent when crossing the 0 line?  My code is below, sorry it's a little messy.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!  I am trying to normalize copcock, QQF and sm_pmi.

```
//@version=4
study("Quantitative Qualitative Estimation, Basic Polychromatic Momentum, Coppock Curve", shorttitle="QQE, CC, PMI",precision=4, resolution="")

//Coppock Curve
section1 = input(false, 'Coppock Curve')
length = input(title="Smoothing Length", type=input.integer, defval=10)
longRocLength = input(title="Long ROC Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)
shortRocLength = input(title="Short ROC Length", type=input.integer, defval=11)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)

coppock = wma(roc(src, longRocLength) + roc(src, shortRocLength), length)

coppockColor = coppock > 0 ? #0ebb23 : color.red

plot(coppock, title="Coppock", linewidth=2, color=coppockColor, transp=0)
hline(0, title="Zero Level", linestyle=hline.style_dotted)


//QQE
section2 = input(false, 'QQE')
src2=input(close)
length2 = input(14,"RSI Length", minval=1)
SSF=input(5, "SF RSI SMoothing Factor", minval=1)
showsignals = input(title="Show Crossing Signals?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
highlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
RSII=ema(rsi(src2,length2),SSF)
TR=abs(RSII-RSII[1])
wwalpha = 1/ length2
WWMA = 0.0
WWMA := wwalpha*TR + (1-wwalpha)*nz(WWMA[1])
ATRRSI=0.0
ATRRSI := wwalpha*WWMA + (1-wwalpha)*nz(ATRRSI[1])
QQEF=ema(rsi(src2,length2),SSF)
QUP=QQEF+ATRRSI*4.236
QDN=QQEF-ATRRSI*4.236
QQES=0.0
QQES:=QUP<nz(QQES[1]) ? QUP : QQEF>nz(QQES[1]) and QQEF[1]<nz(QQES[1]) ? QDN :  QDN>nz(QQES[1]) ? QDN : QQEF<nz(QQES[1]) and QQEF[1]>nz(QQES[1]) ? QUP : nz(QQES[1])
QQF=plot((QQEF-50)*3,"FAST",color.maroon,2)
//QQFLAG=plot(QQEF[1]-50,"P.FAST",color.maroon,2, transp=100)
QQS=plot((QQES-50)*3,"SLOW",color=color.blue, linewidth=1)
//plot(0,color=color.gray,style=6)
longFillColor = highlighting ? (QQEF>QQES ? color.green : na) : na
shortFillColor = highlighting ? (QQEF<QQES ? color.red : na) : na
//fill(QQF, QQS, title="UpTrend Highligter", color=longFillColor)
//fill(QQF, QQS, title="DownTrend Highligter", color=shortFillColor)


//Basic Polychromatic Momentum Indicator
section3 = input(false, 'PMI')
// User inputs
//src3 = input(close, title="Source")
len = input(14, title="Length", minval=1)
//alertcondition = input(title="Enable Alert?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

// Calculation of Polychromatic Momentum Indicator
mom = src - src[len]
pmi = (mom - (mom - mom[len]) / len) * 130

// Smoothed PMI
smoothing = input(2, title="Smoothing", minval=1)
sm_pmi = sma(pmi, smoothing)

// Plotting
plot(sm_pmi, title="PMI", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

Tried the normalize function for variables copcock, QQF and sm_pmi.

```
normalize(_src, _min, _max) => Normalizes series with unknown min/max using historical min/max.
_src      : series to rescale.
_min, _min: min/max values of rescaled series. var _historicMin =  10e10 var _historicMax = -10e10
_historicMin := min(nz(_src, _historicMin), _historicMin)
_historicMax := max(nz(_src, _historicMax), _historicMax)
_min + (_max - _min) * (_src - _historicMin) / max(_historicMax - _historicMin, 10e-10)

normalized_coppock = normalize(coppock, -100, 100) normalized_QQF = normalize(QQF, -100, 100) normalized_sm_pmi = normalize(sm_pmi, -100, 100)

plot(normalized_coppock, title="Coppock", linewidth=2, color=coppockColor, transp=0) plot(normalized_QQF, "FAST",color.maroon,2) plot(normalized_sm_pmi, title="PMI", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

However now they won't cross 0 when they should and seem to be a little offset.